# Filling a UIScrollView w/ PageControl within a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

I'm trying to create a paginated UIScrollView within a view that only scrolls horizontally and is populated by labels.
There are 4 labels and each label shows a string derived from a NSDate, with each one being linked to a PageControl to show which page the user is on.

I'm having a little trouble trying to figure this out based on sample code and other answers.

If I've already dragged out the dimensions on IB, do I still need to specify the frame and such?

Do I then have to create views with labels on them? Or can I simply create labels and populate the UIScrollView?

Is there any way to get the background of the UIScrollView transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `UILabel`s directly to the scroll view as they are a subclass of `UIView`.  If you have already specified the size and position of a view in IB, you do not need to do it again programmatically, although you may.  `myScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` will make your UIScrollView transparent.

Comment: This helped a bit, thanks. I think I maybe looking in the wrong direction though, I think instead I might want to do views with a pagecontroller.